# Symfony3 display an image with asset

Tags: image, symfony, assetic

Symfony gets on my nerves...

I'm desperatly trying to display an image using the following codes and commands :

```
{% image 'EC/myBundle/Resources/public/images/my-image.jpg' %}
 <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

or

```
<img src="{{ asset( 'images/my-image.jpg' ) }}"  />
```

with

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

or with

```
php bin/console assetic:watch
```

or with

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

I've been trying everything but it doesn't work at all.
(However, CSS and JavaScript do work (using the proper tag).)

I don't understand where the problem comes from.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is your image located?

Comment: @thhan , the image is in "public/images/my-image.jpg" folder of my bundle.

Comment: Did you try `php bin/console assets:install --symlink web`?  Are you getting 404 or 403 errors?  Do you see the assets installed in your `web` folder?  Are you using assetic?  Did you try `@myBundle` instead of the path?

Comment: @JasonRoman
Yes I tried this command, it is a `404 error`, no assets installed in the web folder, I am using assetic and yes I tried `@myBundle`. So you can understand my disappointment !

Comment: So you have a `web/bundles` folder with your CSS and JS but not your images?

Comment: At last I succeeded in putting the images into `web/bundles/(...)` but still, they're not displayed...

Comment: Now that you see them, do the images display if you do explicitly call them like`<img src="web/bundles/the/path/to/my-image.jpg"  />` ?

Comment: @JasonRoman It doesn't work either :-/

Comment: @EmmCall Do you try `php bin/console assets:install --symlink  --relative`?

Comment: @thhan I just found the solution, the good path was : `bundles/ecmrp/images/` 
Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for having taken your time :-/ @JasonRoman

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :
img src="/bundles/app/images/logo.png"
and make sure the file exists in the web folder